# Changing javascript confirm dialog box to bootstrap

Tags: javascript, php, html, database, twitter-bootstrap

I already this something

Here is the original code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function delete_user( id ){

    var answer = confirm('Are you sure?');

    //if user clicked ok
    if ( answer ){
        //redirect to url with action as delete and id to the record to be deleted
        window.location = 'delete.php?id=' + id;
    }
}
</script>
```

How do I remove the old javascript confirm dialog box and replace it with bootstrap?

Comment: I think this will [help](http://bootboxjs.com/examples.html) you. Confirm box and also customized box.

Answer (score 0):

The method 'confirm', which shows a modal confirmation dialog box, is associated with the XPInstall API that was used by Mozilla Firefox. This method has been deprecated since Gecko 1.9 and most likely will not be configurable by bootstrap. References can be seen at: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Mozilla/XPInstall/Reference/Install_Object/Methods/confirm and  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Mozilla/XPInstall