# Bootbox javascript confirm dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootbox

I have a problem with this line of code :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function delete_user( id ){

    var answer = confirm('Are you sure?');

    //if user clicked ok
    if ( answer ){
        //redirect to url with action as delete and id to the record to be deleted
        window.location = 'delete.php?id=' + id;
    }
}
</script>
```

How to apply the bootbox.js here. i hate the old javascript dialog box. how can i change this?

i already did this line :

```
<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

still not working.

Comment: Why not just modify/improve your [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25468389/changing-javascript-confirm-dialog-box-to-bootstrap)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this :

Suppose you have button for delete

```
<button class="delete-it">Delete</delete>
```

Write the this under click event of class `delete-it`

```
 $(".delete-it").click(function(){
    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result) {
      if(result)
          window.location = 'delete.php?id=' + id;
    }); 
  });
```

**As per comments below :**

Using `onclick` is considered as bad practice. If you have `$id` value wrap it on data-attribute like this

`<a href='#' data-id=' {$id }' class='delete-it'>Delete</a>`

And change JS in to this :

```
 $(".delete-it").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result) {
      if(result)
          window.location = 'delete.php?id=' + id;
    }); 
  });
```

Comment: i dont have a button for delete. only a echo "<a href='#' onclick='delete_user( {$id} );'>Delete</a>";   how can i apply that.?

Comment: Using `onclick` is bad practice, you can change anchor tag in to `<a href='#' class='delete-it'>Delete</a>` and then use the function I have provided above.

Comment: you mean this : ? <script src="js/bootbox.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(".delete-it").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result) {
      if(result)
          window.location = 'delete.php?id=' + id;
    }); 
  });
}

Comment: ^ Yes, place this script after loading bootbox and jquery libraries.

Comment: THANKS you very much... the response of the click is fast .compared to the other one. that takes two clicks before the data is removed.

Comment: Glad I helped. Upvote if you want others to find the right answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can display the `confirm` dialog box in `bootbox` as follows

```
bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to Delete?", function(result) {
  if(result)
      window.location = 'delete.php?id=' + id;
});
```

You will get the `result` either as `True` or `False` depending on clicking on `Yes` or `No` in the `Dialog Box`.

For further information on `bootbox` confirm dialog box, you can look into [here](http://bootboxjs.com/)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<!-- JS dependencies -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- bootbox code -->
<script src="bootbox.min.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>

function delete_user( id )
{
    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result) 
    {
        answer = result;
    }); 

    //if user clicked ok
    if ( answer ){
        //redirect to url with action as delete and id to the record to be deleted
        window.location = 'delete.php?id=' + id;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: still not working. :( im new a bootstraping and still experimenting

Comment: already working thants S.Pols! i just apply : <script src="js/bootbox.min.js"></script>